# TcpListener packets forwarding

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am writing a HTTP(S)+Mail proxy server. I am using TCPListener to capture packets. Here is the code how I am capturing packets:

```
private async Task startAcceptClientsAsync()
{
        while (this.hasServerStarted)
        {
            var acceptedClient = await this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            this.tcpClients.Add(acceptedClient);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)acceptedClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

            var requestSteram = acceptedClient.GetStream();
            var isRequestAllowed = await this.accessControlManager.IsRequestAllowed(ipEndPoint, requestSteram);

            if (isRequestAllowed)
            {
                // Does not work!!!
                await acceptedClient.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint.Address.ToString(), ipEndPoint.Port);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(); // TODO: Handle unauthorized.
            }
        }
}
```

I am capturing packets and make a decision if request can be accepted or not based on sender IP and request contents. The problem is if request is accepted how can I send to default gateway, get an answer and return?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in general? here you accept connection, you don't read data

Comment: What I want to achieve is to intercept request and return to client the original response. The problem is that I cannot get original address since I am intercepting via proxy. Say client wants to reach google.com - I intercept the request, and I should send him the contents of google.com page (I know google works over https). However the same should work for all protocols (Jabber, telnet, ssh, whatever) and here comes the problem

Comment: You should get the target address in the stream, parse it. Instantiate a WebClient and connect to the target address you just parsed. Get the result and write back to client stream.